# Open URL in Linux using Perl (or any language)?

Tags: perl, shell, lwp

I am new to Perl scripting. I wanted to parse a text file, encode the parsed text and attach in URL. Please point me to right resources if you know any.  This is my major problem.

Now I try to get a URL running and save it in a text file using LWP module in Perl. I used the following program to connect to Google but I am getting "401 UNAUTHORIZED" error. Please help - where I should provide my user authentication details and password?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use LWP::UserAgent;
    use HTTP::Request::Common qw(GET);
    use HTTP::Cookies;

    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

    # Define user agent type
    $ua->agent('Mozilla/8.0');

    # Cookies
    $ua->cookie_jar(
        HTTP::Cookies->new(
            file => 'mycookies.txt',
            autosave => 1
        )
    );

    # Request object
    my $req = GET 'http://www.google.com';

    # Make the request
    my $res = $ua->request($req);

    # Check the response
    if ($res->is_success) {
        print $res->content;
    } else {
        print $res->status_line . "\n";
    }

    exit 0;
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Some quick comments: (1) why are you making a request object rather than calling `$ua->get('google.com')`? (2) to make this whole operation easier you might check out the `WWW::Mechanize` module, which uses `LWP` but wraps it in a more browser-like way (http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Mechanize)

Answer (score 1):

As I have mentioned in my comment to your question, [`WWW::Mechanize`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize) is a wrapper for `LWP` modules. It use resembles how one might use a browser, and it does cookie handling automatically.

To address your direct question, one method it provides is [`credentials`](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.68/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#%24mech-%3Ecredentials%28_%24username,_%24password_%29) to:

> Provide credentials to be used for HTTP Basic authentication for all sites and realms until further notice.

Here is a quick example, similar to your own. User credentials line is commented as I do not expect that google needs them.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
#$mech->credentials('username','password');

$mech->get('http://www.google.com');

if ($mech->success) {
  $mech->dump_text();
  #$mech->save_content('file.html');
} else {
  print $mech->status();
}
```

In summary, `LWP` gives you the power to browser the web, `WWW::Mechanize` makes it more convenient to Do What You Mean.

Answer (score -2):

You better use `LWP::Simple` as this is a quite simple and straightforward operation, usage example:

```
 use LWP::Simple;
 $content = get("http://www.sn.no/");
 die "Couldn't get it!" unless defined $content;
```